# Duplication in ng-repeat with filter applied

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to output an object with specific blood group. I am using a Filter for it.

I am getting duplication error on this. I used chrome debugger and found out that its executing multiple times. Data is passed to filter in each iteration and filter do its complete work from scratch each time.

This is my Filter method

```
Filters.filter('bloodFilter', function() {
  var i, filtered = [];
  return function(data, bloodGroup) {
    if (!data) {
      data = GitHub.USERS;
    }
    if (!bloodGroup) {
      bloodGroup = 'O+'
    }
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      var value = data[i];

      if (value.blood === bloodGroup) {
        filtered.push(value);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  }
});
```

This is My Data

```
GitHub.USERS = [
  {
    fname: "Usman",
    lname: "Tahir",
    blood: "O+"
  },
  {
    fname: "Ali",
    lname: "Hassan",
    blood: "B+"
  },
  {
    fname: "Aqib",
    lname: "Javed",
    blood: "AB+"
  }

];
```

This is my Controller

```
Controllers.controller('BodyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = GitHub.USERS;
});
```

and this is my index code

```
  <body ng-controller="BodyController">    
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="item in users | bloodFilter">
         <b>{{item.fname}}</b> {{item.lname}} {{item.blood }}
       </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

Comment: Is it duplication *error* or just that it is running multiple times?

Comment: where is `bloodGroup`

Comment: filter defined at top. I guess I found problem. Let me answer my own Question :D

Answer (score 1):

Issue is related to JavaScript Closures. I defined array to return outside return block which created problem.

My Filter Function Should be like this, `i` and `filtered` should be inside return block.

```
Filters.filter('bloodFilter', function() {
  return function(data, bloodGroup) {
    var i, filtered = [];
    if (!data) {
      data = GitHub.USERS;
    }
    if (!bloodGroup) {
      bloodGroup = 'O+'
    }
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      var value = data[i];

      if (value.blood === bloodGroup) {
        filtered.push(value);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  }
});
```